# Amplifying and filtering a phototransistor circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, phototransistor

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmV94b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm about at my wit's end here trying to figure this out and hope someone can help me with this.

I'm trying to detect three frequencies (a 5V square wave at 25Hz, 225Hz, and 665 Hz emitted by an IR LED, separated from a phototransistor by about 2 meters (roughly 6.5 feet). My understanding is that this is a sensing circuit with the IR LED acting as a beacon.

These are the steps I've taken so far

- Set up the phototransistor in a transimpedence configuration.
- The junction between the resistor chosen and the phototransistor is fed into a sensing circuit, and then through a high-pass filter (although now that I type this out, maybe a bandpass filter might be more appropriate).

I used a calculator online to determine the component values, but I'm not able to amplify the signal at all after multiple attempts. Could someone walk me through this? If more information is needed, please. let me know.

Datasheets for components used:
LTR-4206E: https://optoelectronics.liteon.com/upload/download/DS-50-92-0073/R4206E.pdf

LTE-4208: https://optoelectronics.liteon.com/upload/download/ds-50-92-0015/lte-4208.pdf

TLV272: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv272.pdf?ts=1696892372986&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTLV272

Comment: *If more information is needed, please. let me know.* <-- schematic, power rails used, component values, links to main data sheets, details of emitter circuit along with some form of proof that it is working (maybe a test that you did).

Comment: Sure. 

So to create the beacon, I've used a TLE-4208 IR LED in series with a 100Ω resistor, powered by a 5V square wave. This is placed 2m (~6.5ft away)

I'm using the TLR-4206E IR phototransistor. I will upload a schematic to the original post. I appreciate your help Andy.

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried to simulate your circuit? I usually cheat on the photodiode/transistor part and substitute with a current source from calculated values of known input light.

Comment: Added the datasheets for the components to the original question as well.

Comment: Your 2nd op-amp circuit (on the right) makes no sense at all. There is a circuit schematic tool available when you edit your question. Why not use it.

Comment: Hi @winny, I haven't yet! Do you suggest any particular simulator to use?

Comment: Everything must be done in such a way as to satisfy the input requirements of the microcontroller, i.e. you must do the "signal conditioning". I'm not clear on the question about the three signals, that is, the system must be able to receive signals at three different frequencies, right?

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for that, I didn't realize I could use it. I have updated my schematic using the tool. Does the error happen in the second op-amp?

Comment: Hi @Franc, so I have the LEDs connected to the microcontroller at the moment that light up when a particular frequency is detected.  When I have the IR LED and IR phototransistor right beside each other, I was able to change the frequency going through the IR LED and the corresponding light turned on; however, anything further than 2 inches doesn't get detected and I assume this is because the signal from the phototransistor is too weak following the increase in distance. Do you think this is the right reasoning?

Comment: Your circuit is very strange, you connect the power supply of the first OpAmp to the collector of the phototransistor and to the inverting input of the same. I doubt it works properly. If the first OpAmp is to function as a simple buffer, then you must power it correctly and connect the inverting input to the OpAmp output and the non-inverting input to the phototransistor collector. At the output of the first OpAmp, connect the signal matching circuit to meet the input requirements of the microcontroller.

Comment: I use LTspice but many recommend Falstad as it may be easier to get started with. Both are free.

Comment: At that kind of distance, without special optics (well collimated LED and transistor, retroreflector if return sensing application), the phototransistor will never be enough gain; most likely you need a lock-in amplifier for this.

Comment: Will ambient light levels be consistent in your application? If not, AC coupling will have to be at the sensor, not after the amp. If you don't know whether it will, I would assume not; notice the receiver does not specify spectral sensitivity, so it can be assumed to respond to visible light, if maybe not as well as to IR.

Answer (score 1):

An op-amp won't bias its own non-inverting pin: -

[image]

Comment: So in this case, you're recommending I do another voltage divider (Vref of 2.5V) and then R7 should connect to the inverting input instead? I appreciate the explaination.

Comment: Try connecting a 100 k resistor between both op-amp non inverting inputs. Your feedback resistor on the left hand op-amp is also badly placed.

Answer (score 0):

You do not show the power rails supplying your op-amps. However, you have R3 connected between the positive rail pin of the OA1. Perhaps you meant R3 to be connected to the output?

OA2 has a resistor connected to the non-inverting input, and a feedback resistor from the output to the inverting input. This configuration makes the OA2 a buffer with a gain of 1. If that is what you want, the resistors are not necessary. If you wanted some other gain, you need a different resistor configuration.

V2 is configured strangely IMHO. Did you mean R2 to be connected to the positive side of V2, and the negative side connected to ground?

You have AC coupling between the first op-amp and the second. There is no DC bias applied to the 2nd op-amp, except for the op-amp's input bias current. Thus the voltage on the right hand side of the capacitor will tend to drift toward a supply rail. This will interfere with proper transmission of your signal through the 2nd op-amp.

At a bare minimum, add a resistor to the right of the capacitor to ground.

Comment: Sure, I'll give that a go, thank you! Is there a way to determine what this resistor value should be or is it through trial and error that I should determine what this value is?

Comment: I would start with something around 47k. The exact value isn't that critical, but you want it to be large enough to not load the left hand side of the circuit too much, but small enough so that the (small) input bias current doesn't result in too large a voltage drop across it.

Comment: Great, I'll update my schematic to include it. I really appreciate your help and explaining it to me.

Comment: Please don't change your question in a way that invalidates the answer! The point of this site is to have questions that are useful to someone else. If you change the question, the answer may not make sense any more.

Comment: Oh right! Will keep it out but will keep it in mind. Thank you!

Comment: Following up on your comment. I did change the schematic to include a change where the OA2 resistor was and connected the op-amps to their power rails. This was a mistake on my part!

Comment: @CharlesHarkin 1) You made your circuit worse with respect to OA2. 2) You should not modify the schematic after you have been given answers. I am rolling back your change.

Comment: Apologies for that. If I have an updated schematic, what is the best approach to share it?

Comment: If you want to ask a question about your new schematic, 1) post ane question with that schatic, 2) include a reference to the old question, 3) explain that the schematic is different and indicate the changes you made.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In a more sophisticated system, the phototransistor is part of a Wheatstone bridge followed by an instrumentation amplifier (the first rectangle in red) the output signal must be compared with the reference one and the output is the right one for the microcontroller. Sorry if I didn't write the component values.

[image]

The instrumentation amplifier (consisting of the first three OpAmps) is, if I remember correctly, the INA411, the second group of three OpAmps is a differential which is also integrated. Then there is the source of the reference voltage which, for example, is 5V, then it is nothing more than a 7205. therefore, ultimately, three OpAmps and some resistors and a trimmer are needed. But I'm already thinking of another solution.

Comment: You need to reference the image back to its source or, if you created it then you should say so or, make it more apparent.

Comment: That's okay, I appreciate the diagram! But can this be done using two op-amps or does it require as many as you have indicated?

Comment: @Franc Can you provide a source for the image?

Comment: I designed everything myself using Windows Paint. Some time ago I created a palette with Paint where there is everything needed to draw the circuits, I just need to select and copy and paste.

Comment: The instrumentation amplifier (consisting of the first three OpAmps) is, if I remember correctly, the INA411, the second group of three OpAmps is a differential which is also integrated. Then there is the source of the reference voltage which, for example, is 5V, then it is nothing more than a 7205. Therefore, ultimately, three OpAmps and some resistors and a trimmer are needed. But I'm already thinking of another solution.